# Detecting memory leaks in C programs?

Tags: c, memory-leak-detector

If we would like to check for memory leaks in a C++ program, we can overload the `new` and `delete` operators to keep track of the memory that was allocated. What if we would like to check for leaks in a C program? Since there is no operator overloading in C, can we over-write the `malloc` function pointer to intercept calls to `malloc` and track memory allocation? Is there an easier way without using any external utilities? Please provide some code as I am not familiar with over-writing method pointers.

Note: I would like to do this without any external utilities for practice.

Comment: @MitchWheat i mentioned that i cant use any external utilities

Comment: Well, if this is for learning, you could learn about how valgrind does it...

Comment: @Mike G: sure you can write your own. you can also wear hair shirts...

Comment: Although excoriated by some, [Writing Solid Code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WritingSolidCode) has some interesting ideas.  For the excoriation, see the the review at [ACCU](http://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=467).  The book is old and dates from just after the C89 standard was finished and before all compilers supported it; it is a little quaint in places.  But memory allocation tracking is discussed extensively, and the general attitude ('Fortify your subsystems', etc) is good.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As suggested, there already exist excellent tools like Valgrind to do this.

Further:

**I would like to do this without any external utilities for practice**
This is interesting and I am sure would be fulfilling,
You can use macro trick to detect such memory usage and leak errors, in fact write your own neat leak detector. You should be able to do this as long as you have a single allocation and deallocation function in your project.

```
#define malloc(X) my_malloc( X, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)

void* my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char *func)
{

    void *p = malloc(size);
    printf ("Allocated = %s, %i, %s, %p[%li]\n", file, line, func, p, size);

    /*Link List functionality goes in here*/

    return p;
}
```

You maintain a Linked List of addresses being allocated with the file and line number from where there allocated. You update the link list with entries in your `malloc`.

Similar to above you can write an implementation for `free`, wherein you check the address entries being asked to be freed against your linked list. If there is no matching entry its a usage error and you can flag it so.

At the end of your program you print or write the contents of your linked list to an logfile. If there are no leaks your linked list should have no entries but if there are some leaks then the logfile gives you exact location of where the memory was allocated.

Note that in using this macro trick, you lose the type checking which functions offer but it's a neat little trick I use a lot of times.

Hope this helps and All the Best :)

Comment: This is definitely and interesting approach, can i just add size to some counter when malloc is invoked then subtract size when free is invoked ?

Comment: You could but that's not going to give you the granularity you might want.  So you lost 2000 bytes.  Was it one 2000 byte allocation or 10 200 byte allocations?  A list would save you a lot of time going through a log trying to match things up.

Comment: @MikeG: Yes, As Duck rightly said, the linked list gives you the flexibility and functionality to accurately determine the faulting allocations.

Comment: We can use LD_PRELOAD too to override the malloc & free calls.

Comment: OP did not say platform. LD_PRELOAD may not applicable.

Comment: can you also post the code how the implementation of `free` looks like. That's more important.

Comment: @dicaprio: I already explained what your version of `free()` should do. The macro trick will be similar: `#define free(X) free( X, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)` and inside the function, You should check if `X` has a match in the Linked list which you populated in `malloc()`.if there's no entry the `free` call was called on incorrect pointer.If entry is found you simply remove that entry from the list.At the end of program if you print link list you get all pointers on which `free` was never called, those are leaks.Try implementing it,If you face a prob ask a Q or leave me a comment here.

Comment: @AlokSave Don't you think there will be infinite recursion? As we are calling malloc inside my_malloc, which will be preprocessed to my_malloc. So effectively it should result in stack overflow!!!

Comment: Portably recommend instead of `printf("%li\n", size)`, use  `printf("%zu\n", size)` or  `printf("%lli\n", (long long) size)`.

Comment: @AlokSave I had the same question as Yogesh . Is calling malloc() from my_malloc() appropriate? And if it's possible why isn't it going into infinite recursive calls?

Comment: @SunilShahu  the self reference rule of macros avoid the infinite loop. Pls see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_3.html#SEC31

Answer (score 19):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is what you need.

I remember reading first chapter of [Algorithms in a Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516246.do) which talked about this although it didn't include code. Just added in case you find it interesting.

> since there is no operator overloading in c can we over-write malloc
>   function point to intercept calls to malloc and track memory
>   allocation

Actually, you can. GIve LD_PRELOAD a read.

Comment: I know how to use Valgrind i just want to implement it myself

Comment: @MikeG: This is like if you have cancer and you "know about hospitals, but want to try curing it myself for practice".

Comment: @KerrekSB: Nothing wrong in playing around with it, It sure is a great learning experience.Ofcourse, valgrind is the best when on a real time project environment but well I must admit this was a good learning for me when I did it long time ago.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Als's answer which will wrap calls in your source code, if you're using gnu `ld`, you can have the linker wrap all calls (presumably to `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`, and `free`) at link time, irrespective of where they come from. You then write `__wrap_malloc` etc and can call the original function with, for example, `__real_malloc`.

See `--wrap=symbol` in http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html

I don't know how this works with calls from shared libraries. I'm guessing it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Use mallinfo function it worked for me on Xilinx Zynq baremetal using Xilinx SDK gcc.  I tested with intentional memory leak - I have no idea why but google results are were incredibly terrible at finding this solution spread the word to help other devs!