# Memory leak detection and analysis tool

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

Actually, I know it's necessary to free the memory allocated with malloc(), but I wonder if I can know there is some memory left being not collected if I forget to collect it with free().

Comment: Check out [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting memory leaks in C programs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074229/detecting-memory-leaks-in-c-programs)

Comment: There may be more helpful information here in addition to the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074229/detecting-memory-leaks-in-c-programs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind would be your best bet

http://valgrind.org/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to valgrind answers, you may link your executables against Boehm GC – C garbage collector that may run in leak detection mode.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector
http://www.hboehm.info/gc/
http://www.hboehm.info/gc/leak.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like valgrind. Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvTsFjDuag8) on how to use it, courtesy of Harvard's CS50 available on edx. It gives a very good explanation on how to use it, as well as some examples on both correct and incorrect code.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Just keep track of all the memory you allocated and erase it when needed

Comment: That fact that you didn't see leak detection tools before doesn't free you from googling some keywords before providing *such* wrong answers.

Comment: I have seen leak detection tools but they detect and dont actively free the memory